# Limiting by date field availability on Cognito Form

Tags: cognito-forms

I rent equipment on my Cognito form and I don't want customers to be able to rent equipment after midnight of the previous day.  We need time to set up their rental.

I know I can change the range on the date form to the follow day, but can it be set to automatically change when the clock strikes midnight?  Bottom line, I don't want rentals available the same day.  Only next day or future rentals (many days in advance) can be booked.

Example: A user can book a snowboard on 18 January 2016 for 19 January 2016 or 25 January 2016, but can't book it for 18 January 2016 (same day rental).

Answer (score 1):

In [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com), you can specify both static and calculated values for range limits for numeric and date fields.  In the case of dates, you can also use some simple relative dates as part of these limits.

In this case, just enter `Tomorrow` as the Minimum for the date range.  This will also visually gray out dates before tomorrow when they use the date picker.

[image]